# How can I make yogurt at home?

Tags: food-safety, milk, yogurt

What are the requirements for making yogurt at home. Is there a solid recipe for making yogurt?

Comment: There are hundreds of articles on the net on this, which ones did you try?

Answer (score 14):

I was sure that with all the questions and answers we have had about yogurt that this simple question must surely have already been asked. But I couldn't find it.

Making yogurt is simplicity itself.

The goal is to introduce heat-loving (thermophillic) bacteria to milk, keep them warm so that they munch on the lactose in the milk turning it into lactic acid. The acidity and warmth denatures the milk proteins and turns the whole mass into a gel.

The steps may vary a little depending on your equipment and the bacteria that you use.

1. **Get milk.** -- The more fat the better it will taste. Powdered milk can also be added to improve the texture as it will add more protein.
2. **Get a starter.** -- Any commercial yogurt that advertises "live active cultures" will work just fine. Pick a yogurt that you like as the yogurt you make with those cultures will be similar.
3. **Heat the milk** to about 85°C (190°F) for a few minutes. -- This will denature the albumin in the milk which will add to the yogurt structure instead of leaking out with the whey.
4. **Cool the milk** at to between 40°C (110-120°F). -- 55°C (130°F) will kill your starter.
5. **Mix in** the starter.
6. **Keep the mix warm for 6-10 hours.** -- The longer the more acidic and firm it will get. The exact temperature will depend on your starter and equipment. Danon plain yogurt, as a starter, wants to stay at 37°C (100-110°F). My Indian coworker's starter that she brought from India can thrive at almost room temperatures.
   "Yogurt makers" can be purchased that simply hold their contents at about 100F. Some people use heating pads. Some people set their oven on low. You can be creative- just don't get hotter than 55°C (130°F) or cooler than 30°C (90°F) or so. 
    To try it out for the first time I would recommend simply putting your yogurt in a heavy, lidded, container, wrapping in a towel and letting it sit in the turned-off oven for 5-6 hours.
7. For a thicker creamier texture you can **strain your yogurt**. -- After it has fermented to your liking stir it up well, pour it into a piece of muslin in a strainer, and let it drain for a little while. The whey draining off is good for baking. It has some calcium, b12, and a lot of lactose. (If you skipped step 3 it also has a lot of wasted protein).

Making your own yogurt is a fun activity. You get to pick what goes into it so there is no sneaky ingredients and you can make it for a fraction of the cost of commercial. Play around with different starters. Different bacteria will produce yogurt with different qualities and it is interesting to experiment.

Comment: My grandmother wraps the jars with still hot mix in an old parka and lets them sit there. Cheapest temperature retaining option. Hard to controll, but obviously works for her.

Comment: I have noticed that the better the yogurt- the less likely the maker is to know the science behind it. :( My Indian coworker's mother's instructions were decidedly unscientific.

Comment: If you're handy with electronics - you can automate some of this http://makeprojects.com/Project/Yobot-Arduino-Yogurt-Maker/499/1

Comment: A milk boiler is a worthy investment; my mother *never* flubbed her yogurt after purchasing one. They're a double-layer of stainless steel with a hollow space to fill with water. Water, with its high specific heat, helps maintain the right temperature. Also, I've found that 2% gets me the perfect whey/curd ratio for my tastes, though that could be more a product of my bacterial culture than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my recipe.

1. Add 1/4 cup milk powder and 1 TBSP honey to a 1/2 gallon of milk and heat it to 190 for a few minutes.
2. Cool the milk quickly in a sink filled with cold water to 110 degees.
3. Whisk some hot milk to your room temperature yogurt starter and then incorporate it back into the pot.
4. Place the pot of yogurt into a food dehydrator which has a thermostat and a timer. Set the temperature to 115 and let it run for 6 to 10 hours.  It keeps a constant temperature so there is no wrapping the pot, or turning the oven on and off to try to maintain the correct temperature!
5. Remove it from the dehydrator, wisk it to get a smooth and silky texture and transfer it to jars and store in the fridge.